# cannot display multiple image

Tags: php, html, mysql

Image cannot be displayed in html page.

for example code :

```html
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data =mysql_query("select * from img_homestay WHERE id='$id'");


   while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
   {         
    $location = $row['location'];
    echo '<img src="'.$location.'" width=30% height=10%>';
 echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="#" imgid="'.$row['imgid'].'" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">Delete</a></div></td>';
    echo "<br>"; 
 }

?>
```

Comment: what comes in $row['location']? Whole path to image ?

Comment: You need to `close` that `img` tag first as `<img src='$location'  width='30%' height='10%'>`

Comment: i think $location didn't get the value in inside the tag,try this..
echo '<img src='$location' width="30%" height="10%">';

Comment: @Khushboo its contain details path to image

Comment: @Marcus already edit. but still cannot displayed.

Comment: @SathishS same. nothing change anything

Comment: please print $location only

Comment: echo $location and add its result in your question

Comment: echo '<img src="'.$location.'" width=30% height=10%>'; this code is working properly on my server i have a $location = "myimage.jpg" and the image in the same folder and its displaying ok, so maybe your $location is wrong or you dont have that image on that $location on your server

Comment: Please use var_dump($location) if result true, after that you check the path of image src,

Comment: @Geomorillo its about location. thanks

Answer (score 0):

One obvious mistake in your code is that the closing tag '>' is missing for img. So it needs to be

```
echo "<img src='$location' width='30%' height='10%'>";
```

Apart from this be sure $location var has the correct absolute or relative path picked from DB to show the image. Then, you are using $id in the query. Be sure this is not the unique ID in the img_homestay table, as that will only return you one row. I believe you want to fetch all the images for a particular post id, so ensure that you are using that ID only for the correct field in the query.

Another suggestion that done switch between double quote and single quote string notation in PHP. This will make your code hard to read and comprehend. In one echo statement you are using

```
echo " ";
```

and in next statement you are using:

```
echo ' ';
```

Comment: what are the values you are getting in $location. Also, if there is a live testing page, please share the link that so that it can be inspected.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data =mysql_query("select * from img_homestay WHERE id='".$id."'");


while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{         
$location = $row['location'];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $location;?>" width="30%" height="10%">
<td><div align="center"><a href="#" imgid="<?php echo $row['imgid'];?>" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">Delete</a></div></td>
<br> 
<?php   }

 ?>
```

Comment: still cannot display. if change the code, not using $id. it would be displayed all images and also not belonging id

Comment: what is the $id value you are getting

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
 $data =mysql_query("select * from img_homestay WHERE id='".$id."'");
 while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{         
$location = $row['location'];
echo '<img src="'.$location.'" width=30% height=10%>';
echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="#" imgid="'.$row['imgid'].'" class="delbutton" title="Click       To Delete">Delete</a></div></td>';
echo "<br>"; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your processing is wrong. Your query is `select * from img_homestay WHERE id='$id'` which means it's going to fetch a single row (I assume, because you're making a query based on an ID which, I again assume, is a `unique key`) so you actually don't need to use the `while` loop (if you intend to use single image).

Still, if that's not the case, you may need to use `<tr>` for each row, so maybe, try this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data =mysql_query("select * from img_homestay WHERE id=$id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
$location = $row['location'];
echo "<tr><td><img src='$location' width=30% height=10%>";
echo "<td><div align='center'><a href='#' imgid='$row[imgid]' class='delbutton' title='Click To Delete'>Delete</a></div></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Also, I see, you're using `td` here which means, you're using `table` but I see no `table` tags. My guess is, there is some issue in table structure. A better check to see if you're image is being parsed or not would be to check the source code of the rendered HTML page. I'm sure you're getting the `img` tag in resulting HTML but it is not being rendered due to error in HTML structure so you better check and correct your HTML with respect to the table you're using.

Comment: "so you actually don't need to use the while loop", but you are using while loop.

Comment: @Khushboo: I've used the while loop, considering that he actually wants multiple rows. May be you should have analysed the code more closely to find that extra `<tr>` in `while` loop.